# Python sockets - send messages continuously

Tags: python, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi

I have implemented code for a server and a client using sockets, however I would like the server to send continuously and the client to receive and print the message received until I end either program. The code just prints out once "L2" on the client.

Is it ideal to reverse functionality by receiving with the server and sending with the client?

client.py

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname, 1223))

while True:
    msg = s.recv(5)
    # clientsocket.close()
    print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

server.py

```
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1223))
s.listen(3)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    clientsocket.send(bytes("L2", "utf-8"))
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: you have to use `accept()` before `while True`

Comment: it is your server and client and if you need to use `send()` all time in server then do it.

Comment: @furas for the client or server? or both?

Comment: you have `accept()` only in `server` and you should use it before `while True` in server

Comment: BTW: your idea doesn't work like standard `client-server` but rather like [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in which server can send message in any moment and client is listening for messages

Comment: `accept` waits for a new connection. Your server waits for a new connection then sends L2 to it. Then it waits for a new connection then sends L2 to it. And so on.